# Await not awaiting async function

Tags: javascript, async-await

im working on a webscraper for an api, and i was trying to divide it into functions, for whatever reason the await is not awaiting for the promise to be fulfilled

```
const PORT = 8000
const axios = require('axios')
const cheerio = require('cheerio')
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const cors = require('cors')
app.use(cors())

const clarinURL = 'https://www.clarin.com/economia/'

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.json('This is my webscraper')
})

app.get('/results', async (req, res) => {
    let results = await cheerioPick(clarinURL, '.content-nota', 'h2', 'a', 'https://www.clarin.com')
    console.log(results)
    res.send(results)
})

async function cheerioPick(url, container, titletag, urltag, domain) {
    axios(url)
    .then(response => {
        const html = response.data
        const $ = cheerio.load(html)
        const articles = []

        $(container, html).each(function () { //<-- cannot be a function expression
            const title = $(this).find(titletag).text()
            const url = domain + $(this).find(urltag).attr('href')
            articles.push({
                title,
                url
            })
        })
        console.log("articles")
        return articles
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
}

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`server running on PORT ${PORT}`))
```

on the console it prints:

```
undefined
articles
```

so it's clearly not awaiting for the async function to return it's result

Comment: "so it's clearly not awaiting for the async function to return it's result" — It does. That function calls `axios` to set off another set of asynchronous code, reaches that end of the function, and returns a promise that resolves as `undefined` because it has no return statement.

Comment: Convert axios promise to async-await inside cheerioPick.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the function `cheerioPick` is not returning a `Promise`.

There are some ways to get this done. I would recomend use async/await in your axios segment so your whole code use the same approch of the asynchronous coding.

```
async function cheerioPick(url, container, titletag, urltag, domain) {
  try {
    const response = await axios(url);
    const html = response.data
    const $ = cheerio.load(html)
    const articles = []

    $(container, html).each(function () { //<-- cannot be a function expression
        const title = $(this).find(titletag).text()
        const url = domain + $(this).find(urltag).attr('href')
        articles.push({
            title,
            url
        })
    })
    console.log("articles")
    return articles
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
```

Comment: Thanks ariel, I guess I didn't know that .then and async await promises were not interchangeable